# Set default date for created_at and updated_at fields in a Doctrine form

Tags: forms, symfony1, doctrine

I have a symfony form which have created_at and updated_at field for date. But I want to populate this field with default value and not shown when the form shows. So that, the created_at will hold the current time when inserting new data and updated_at will hold current date when updating any data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These fields are automatically handled by propel. Simply unset() the fields in the form, and let propel do the magic :)

If you're using doctrine, add the Timestampable behavior to your class and unset the fields in the form, and it'll work too.

Comment: I'm a propel guy, but as far as I can tell reading the Timestampable behavior's documentation, yes. See http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/en/behaviors#core-behaviors:timestampable

Comment: @sparrow, @maerlyn is right — you just have to unset these fields and Timestampable template will do the job for you. I'm fellow Doctrine user for last 1.5 years :)

Comment: @maerlyn, how about updating your answer so @sparrow could mark it as right one?

Comment: @all, thanks for helping. yes it worked also for doctrine. what i have learnt here is the created_at and updated_at must be created by symfony by actAs: Timestampable, not by hand directly in database. Thanks a lot again to all.

Comment: Timestampable behavior works both using Doctrine or Propel, 100% guaranted !